# data.table: Subtracting levels means from values

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I wonder how to subtract levels means from values in `data.table`. My MWE is given below.

```
set.seed(12345)
A <- rep(x=paste0("A", 1:2), each=6)
B <- rep(x=paste0("B", 1:3), each=2, times=2)
Rep <- rep(x=1:2, times=3)
Y <- rnorm(n=12, mean = 50, sd = 5)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A, B, Rep, Y)

dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A, B)]
dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A)]

dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A, B)] - dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A)]

Error in Ops.data.frame(dt[, j = mean(Y), by = .(A, B)], dt[, j = mean(Y),  : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

**Edited**

I want this one:

```
dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A, B)] - dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A)] - dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(B)] + dt[, j=mean(Y)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get the error is the dimension of the two data.table you are subtracting is different. On the other hand, you can do a chained transformation using `data.table`:

```
dt[, j := mean(Y), .(A, B)][, j := j - mean(Y), .(A)]
dt
     A  B Rep        Y          j
 1: A1 B1   1 52.92764  3.6373822
 2: A1 B1   2 53.54733  3.6373822
 3: A1 B2   1 49.45348 -1.0071061
 4: A1 B2   2 47.73251 -1.0071061
 5: A1 B3   1 53.02944 -2.6302761
 6: A1 B3   2 40.91022 -2.6302761
 7: A2 B1   1 53.15049  0.1752053
 8: A2 B1   2 48.61908  0.1752053
 9: A2 B2   1 48.57920 -3.7182851
10: A2 B2   2 45.40339 -3.7182851
11: A2 B3   1 49.41876  3.5430798
12: A2 B3   2 59.08656  3.5430798
```

For the update, you can do:

```
dt[, j := mean(Y), .(A, B)][, j := j - mean(Y), .(A)][, j := j - mean(Y), .(B)][, j := j + mean(Y)]
dt
     A  B Rep        Y         j
 1: A1 B1   1 52.92764  1.731088
 2: A1 B1   2 53.54733  1.731088
 3: A1 B2   1 49.45348  1.355590
 4: A1 B2   2 47.73251  1.355590
 5: A1 B3   1 53.02944 -3.086678
 6: A1 B3   2 40.91022 -3.086678
 7: A2 B1   1 53.15049 -1.731088
 8: A2 B1   2 48.61908 -1.731088
 9: A2 B2   1 48.57920 -1.355590
10: A2 B2   2 45.40339 -1.355590
11: A2 B3   1 49.41876  3.086678
12: A2 B3   2 59.08656  3.086678
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom for your answer. Wonder how to do complicated computations like this one `dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A, B)] - dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(A)] - dt[, j=mean(Y), by=.(B)] + dt[, j=mean(Y)]`. Thanks

Comment: Similarly, if you chain all the operation together, you should be able to get what you want. Such as `dt[, j := mean(Y), .(A, B)][, j := j - mean(Y), .(A)][, j := j - mean(Y), .(B)][, j := j + mean(Y)]`.

Comment: Note: The OP is using `j` as a named argument of `[.data.table`, but you are actually creating a column with the name `j`... which some (like me) may find confusing.

Comment: @Frank. I see what you concern. However a named argument with `groupby` will lead to different dimension of the result which makes the subtraction difficult. That's why I consider creating a new vector a more straight forward way.

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted and think this is the right way to go; I'd just try to find another name, is what I meant.