# data.table: .SD for the following code

Tags: r, data.table

This is the follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37883056/707145). Wonders how to use `.SD` in this problem (rather than doing computations separately for each variable, in this case for Y1 and Y2 separately).

```
set.seed(12345)
A <- rep(x=paste0("A", 1:2), each=6)
B <- rep(x=paste0("B", 1:3), each=2, times=2)
Rep <- rep(x=1:2, times=3)
Y1 <- rnorm(n=12, mean = 50, sd = 5)
Y2 <- rnorm(n=12, mean = 50, sd = 10)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A, B, Rep, Y1, Y2)

dt[, j = Eff1 := mean(Y1), .(A, B)][, j = Eff1 := Eff1 - mean(Y1), .(A)][, j = Eff1 := Eff1 - mean(Y1), .(B)][, j = Eff1 := Eff1 + mean(Y1)]
dt[, j = Eff2 := mean(Y2), .(A, B)][, j = Eff2 := Eff2 - mean(Y2), .(A)][, j = Eff2 := Eff2 - mean(Y2), .(B)][, j = Eff2 := Eff2 + mean(Y2)]

dt[, j = .(Eff1 = mean(Eff1), Eff2 = mean(Eff2)), by = .(A, B)]
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where/why do you want to use `.SD`? And I'd strongly suggest not typing the explicit `j =`'s.

Comment: Describe your problem and the desired result in natural language.

Comment: Thanks @eddi for your comment and suggestion. Please see my edits for more clarification and suggest more efficient approach to perform these computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would consider going outside the data.table syntax, using `ave`:

```
my_cols  = c("Y1", "Y2")
tmp_cols = c("Eff1", "Eff2")

dt[, (tmp_cols) :=
    lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x) + ave(x, A, B) - ave(x, A) - ave(x, B))
, .SDcols = my_cols][,
    lapply(.SD, mean)    
, by=A:B, .SDcols = tmp_cols]
```

One long way is:

```
dtA  = dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=A, .SDcols = my_cols]
dtB  = dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=B, .SDcols = my_cols]
dtAB = dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(A,B), .SDcols = my_cols]

dt[,    (tmp_cols) := lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = my_cols]
dt[dtAB,(tmp_cols) := Map(`+`, mget(tmp_cols), mget(paste0("i.", my_cols))), on=c("A","B")]
dt[dtA, (tmp_cols) := Map(`-`, mget(tmp_cols), mget(paste0("i.", my_cols))), on="A"]
dt[dtB, (tmp_cols) := Map(`-`, mget(tmp_cols), mget(paste0("i.", my_cols))), on="B"]

dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(A,B), .SDcols=tmp_cols]
```

Comment: Difficult to understand at first sight but very concise and efficient. Thanks a lot.